# XAML Buttons in ListBoxItem template

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a ListBox that has a single select. When item is selected it should show additional options like - edit, delete buttons.

So i have done this:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemStyle}" Loaded="MyList_Loaded">

</ListBox>
```

And here is my template:

```
<Style x:Key="MyItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <!--Deleted to minimize the snippet-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <!--Deleted to minimize the snippet-->
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EditButtons">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <!--Deleted to minimize the snippet-->
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="Transparent" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource BodyContentPresenterStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="13,0,13,13" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="EditButtons">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <HyperlinkButton 
                                x:Name="SendButton" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                IsTabStop="True"
                                TabIndex="3"
                                Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                Content="Send" 
                                Style="{StaticResource HyperlinksStyle}" 
                                />
                            <HyperlinkButton 
                                x:Name="EditButton" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                IsTabStop="True"
                                TabIndex="3"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                Content="Edit" 
                                Style="{StaticResource HyperlinksStyle}" 
                                />
                            <HyperlinkButton 
                                x:Name="DeleteButton" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                IsTabStop="True"
                                TabIndex="3"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                Content="Delete" 
                                Style="{StaticResource HyperlinksStyle}" 
                                />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I cant figure out how can i bind Click handlers to those 3 hyperlink buttons.
I have tried to:

```
private void MyList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sendButton = FindChild<HyperlinkButton>(MyList, "SendButton");
}
```

And

Adding a handler directly in XAML from visual editor.

**But all this didn't work. How can i react to click events of those 3 buttons?**

Comment: @AndriiKrupka nop, but DataContext is self so if you want to suggest binding to a command i would be glad to see an example for UWP

Comment: look my answer. I created sample

Comment: I think you need a DataTemplate in the listbox. You should define all the button with the click event, and hide or not hide them related to the selected value of the listbox item. You need to create a ValueConverter class that implement IValueConverter to convert selected (true/false) values to visibility propertes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the grid with buttons to hide in the listbox's ItemTemplate and click events will be fired.

```
<Page
...
xmlns:converter="using:VisibilyConverter" 
...
>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
       <converter:VisibiliyConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="13,0,13,13" Visibility="{Bindig IsSelected, Mode=OneWay,
                            Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <HyperlinkButton 
                    x:Name="SendButton" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    IsTabStop="True"
                    TabIndex="3"
                    Margin="7,0,0,0"
                    Content="Send" 
                    Style="{StaticResource HyperlinksStyle}" 
                    Click="SendButtonClick
                    />
                <HyperlinkButton 
                    x:Name="EditButton" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    IsTabStop="True"
                    TabIndex="3"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="7,0,0,0"
                    Content="Edit" 
                    Style="{StaticResource HyperlinksStyle}" 
                    Click="EditButtonClick
                    />
                <HyperlinkButton 
                    x:Name="DeleteButton" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    IsTabStop="True"
                    TabIndex="3"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Margin="7,0,0,0"
                    Content="Delete" 
                    Style="{StaticResource HyperlinksStyle}" 
                    Click="DeleteButtonClick
                    />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>


void SendButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

void DeleteButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Will mark this as an answer. You are correct. In my implementation of buttons visibility the events didn't fire - this is strange

Answer (score 1):

When the Template/Style is defined in the same XAML file as the button you can easily use the Click Handler in XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="SendButton" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    IsTabStop="True"
    TabIndex="3"
    Margin="7,0,0,0"
    Content="Send" 
    Style="{StaticResource HyperlinksStyle}" 
    Click="HandleSendClick"
    />

private void HandleSendClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //...
}
```

However, I would recommend you to use [MVVM and Command Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) in general. Using event handlers in WPF is archaic.

Comment: As i said - i have tried to add Click handler in the Template/Style itself - but it doesn't get triggered ( yes it is on the same xaml as the ListBox )

Comment: I uploaded you a simplified solution of your code: https://ufile.io/5e06e
It demonstrates that the click handler works fine.
If it doesn't work in your code there is a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So, install `MvvmLightLibs` nuget package, and create command in your code-behind

```
public RelayCommand<MyClassModel> SendCommand { get; set; }
```

Initialize in ctor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SendCommand = new RelayCommand<MyClassModel>(SendExecute);
    DataContext = this;
}
```

and execute callback:

```
private void SendExecute(MyClassModel item)
{

}
```

In XAML code setup name to `ListBox` and bind your command

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemStyle}"
         x:Name="listBox"/>

<HyperlinkButton x:Name="SendButton" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.SendCommand, ElementName=listBox}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                    IsTabStop="True"
                    TabIndex="3"
                    Margin="7,0,0,0"
                    Content="Send"/>
```